# Unable to create Docker container for Scraproxy

Tags: docker, web-scraping, scrapy, http-proxy

Attempting to get [scraproxy](https://scrapoxy.readthedocs.io/en/master/quick_start/index.html) up and running using docker. Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064579/running-docker-image-on-aws-ec2/45064963#45064963). I can see that I've successfully pulled the scraproxy image:

```
REPOSITORY                   TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
fabienvauchelles/scrapoxy   latest    bcf119a67836   7 weeks ago   146MB
```

However when I run the command to create the container:

```
docker create --name string scrapoxy -e COMMANDER_PASSWORD='text_password'\ 
-e PROVIDERS_AWSEC2_ACCESSKEYID='key_here'\ 
-e PROVIDERS_AWSEC2_SECRETACCESSKEY='key_here'\ 
-it -p 8888:8888 -p 8889:8889 fabienvauchelles/scrapoxy
```

...I get the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'scrapoxy:latest' locally
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for scrapoxy, repository does 
not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

If you can point me in the right direction that would be most appreciated. I'm pretty green when it comes to docker.

Comment: sign up for a docker hub account https://hub.docker.com/ and configure it to your env or you can build it right from the github repo

Comment: I have a docker hub account. When I'm signed in with the docker cloud cli, I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Is there an additional step I need to take to 'configure it to my env'? Do I need to call my docker login when I create the container?

Comment: Is your docker client logged in to the registry? if not check the docs here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

Comment: Which registry? Previously I've been using docker login in the cli, then inputing my username and password. This outputs "Login Succeeded." Assumed this meant I'm logged into docker hub and can pull and push images.